# Java WebService: String XML SAX reading/writing, NOT via file

Tags: java, xml, string, web-services, sax

Researching XML reading/writing by Java/SAX, I found only handling disk files examples - and I need STRING in/out handling. I am coding a WebService with XML input/output, so I need to deal with STRING XML, not files.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This example is for Xerces, one of the best known XML Java parsers:
See http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/javadocs/api/org/xml/sax/XMLReader.html

```
parse

void parse(InputSource input)
           throws java.io.IOException,
                  SAXException

    Parse an XML document.

    The application can use this method to instruct the XML reader 
to begin parsing an XML document from any valid input source
 (a character stream, a byte stream, or a URI).
```

You will have to create an `InputSource` which can be from a multiplicity of sources including characters (Strings).

See http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/javadocs/api/org/xml/sax/InputSource.html

```
public InputSource(java.io.InputStream byteStream)

    Create a new input source with a byte stream.





    Application writers should use setSystemId() to provide a base for 
resolving #relative URIs, may use setPublicId to include a public 
identifier, and may use setEncoding to specify the object's character encoding.
```

You may find that your XML toolkit has alternatives including `InputStream`. If so, you can use a `ByteArrayInputStream` formed from your string. A bit long-winded, but it works.

Comment: Is this what you wanted? And is it enough to show how to proceed? If not, can you post your current code for files?